# How to change resolution (with Bumblebee)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution, bumblebee

I need to change the resolution on my laptop, unfortunately, xrandr only shows something like that. By nvidia-settings doesn't work.

```
xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1368 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768
default connected primary 1368x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1366x768 0.0
1368x768 0.0* 

sudo lshw -c display
*-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 09
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:d3000000-d33fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

How to change resolution?

Ubuntu 13.10
Lenovo g500s
Intel Pentium 2020M 2.4 GHz
Intel HD Graphics (Ivy Bridge), 350-1100 MHz, 9.17.10.2963 + NVIDIA® GeForce GT720 M
4096 MB , DDR3, Single-Channel
Screen 15.6 16:9, 1366x768, Samsung L ATLTN156AT30L01, TN,